# Asymptotic solution to a differential equation near zero

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, asymptotics

I am trying to get the both the asymptotic solutions of the equation $y''(x)=\sqrt{x} \cdot y(x)$ as $x\rightarrow 0$.  But when I put $y(x)=\exp(S(x))$ since $x=0$ is an irregular singular point, no matter whether I neglect $S''$ or $S'^{2}$, the approximation does not seem to be valid after evaluating the solutions unless I ignore the constant of integration. How can I proceed to get asymptotic expansion of both the solutions? Please provide hints.

Comment: It seems like you'd be better off trying for a series solution like $$y(x) = \sum_{k=0}^{\infty} a_k x^{k/2}.$$  You'll find that $a_0$ and $a_2$ are arbitrary, and the rest are determined by their values.

Comment: @AntonioVargas : thanks for the comment, will I get two solutions from this ?

Comment: Yeah, it ends up looking like $$\begin{align}y(x) &= a_0 \left(1 + \tfrac{4}{15}x^{5/2} + \tfrac{1}{75} x^5 + \tfrac{4}{14625} x^{15/2} + \cdots\right) \\ &\qquad + a_2 \left(x + \tfrac{4}{35} x^{7/2} + \tfrac{2}{525} x^6 + \tfrac{8}{133875} x^{17/2} + \cdots\right)\end{align}$$

Comment: @AntonioVargas : thank you !

Comment: I think I would still have to justify looking for such a series.

Comment: Yeah, I agree, a more careful analysis is required.  Those series may not be valid.

Answer (score 1):

The general solution, according to Maple, is

$$ y(x) = c_1 \sqrt{x}\; I_{2/5}\left(\dfrac{4}{5} x^{5/4}\right)
+ c_2 \sqrt{x} \;K_{2/5}\left(\dfrac{4}{5} x^{5/4}\right)$$
where $I_{2/5}$ and $K_{2/5}$ are modified Bessel functions of the first and second kinds.

The series expansions at $x=0$ (for $x > 0$), again according to Maple, are

$$ \eqalign{ \sqrt{x}\; I_{2/5}\left(\dfrac{4}{5} x^{5/4}\right) &=
{\frac {{2}^{{ {9}/{10}}}{5}^{3/5}\Gamma  \left( 3/5 \right) 
\sqrt {5+\sqrt {5}}}{8 \pi }} x+{\frac {{2}^{{ {9}/{10}}}{5}^{3/5}
\Gamma  \left( 3/5 \right) \sqrt {5+\sqrt {5}}}{70\,\pi }} x^{7/2}\cr &+{
\frac {{2}^{{ {9}/{10}}}{5}^{3/5}\Gamma  \left( 3/5 \right) \sqrt {5+\sqrt {5}}}{2100\,\pi }} x^6+O \left( {x}^{17/2} \right) 
\cr
 \sqrt{x} \;K_{2/5}\left(\dfrac{4}{5} x^{5/4}\right) &=
-{\frac {\pi \,{2}^{1/10}{5}^{2/5}\sqrt {5+\sqrt {5}} \left( -5+
\sqrt {5} \right) }{20 \;\Gamma  \left( 3/5 \right) }}-\dfrac{{2}^{2/5}{5}^{3
/5}\Gamma  \left( 3/5 \right)}{4} x\cr &-{\frac {\pi \,{2}^{1/10}{5}^{2/5}\sqrt {5+\sqrt {5}} \left( -5+\sqrt {5} \right) }{75\,\Gamma 
 \left( 3/5 \right) }} x^{5/2}-\dfrac{{2}^{2/5}{5}^{3/5}\Gamma  \left( 3/5
 \right)}{35} {x}^{7/2}\cr &-{\frac {\pi \,{2}^{1/10}{5}^{2/5}\sqrt {5+
\sqrt {5}} \left( -5+\sqrt {5} \right) }{1500\,\Gamma  \left( 3/5
 \right) }} x^5-{\frac {{2}^{2/5}{5}^{3/5}\Gamma  \left( 3/5 \right) }{1050}} x^6\cr &-{\frac {\pi \,{2}^{1/10}{5}^{2/5}\sqrt {5+\sqrt {
5}} \left( -5+\sqrt {5} \right) }{73125\,\Gamma  \left( 3/5 \right) }} x^{15/2}
+O \left( {x}^{17/2} \right) 
  }$$

So Antonio's series are correct.  You might note, BTW, that the change of dependent variable
$ x = t^2$ gives you a differential equation
$$ t y'' - y' - 4 t^4 y $$ which has a regular singular point at $t=0$, with indicial equation $r^2 - 2 r = 0$, and the recursion for coefficients
$$ a_{i+5} = \dfrac{4}{(i+5)(i+3)} a_i$$
where $$ y = a_0 + a_5 t^5 + a_{10} t^{10} + \ldots = a_0 + a_5 x^{5/2} + a_{10} x^5 + \ldots$$
or
$$ y = a_2 t^2 + a_7 t^7 + a_{12} t^{12} + \ldots = a_2 x + a_7 x^{7/2} +
a_{12} x^6 + \ldots$$